# Searching through multiple amounts of xml data

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have large amounts of XML data files with information in which I need to find information from (ex: phone number that matches: 123-123-1234). I know that XML is not like SQL where I can do a simple query, yet I need to pull information of the XML data. What is a fastest way to do a search through xml with JavaScript? Or is there another way in which I should approach this (maybe somehow try to convert all the xml files to SQL by mapping out the elements, saving it as SQL, and then importing it to a SQL database)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for XPath https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: The thing is I have 10GB+ of files with data that I am going to be looking through. I am not sure how well xpath would be in this case.

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you try anything to accomplish what you want?